# Is "Perl Monger" derogatory when used by non Perl programmers?

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language, nuance

The two most common uses of the word "monger" I've heard of are rather derogatory: whore-monger and warmonger. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monger) reflects this in its second definition:

> A person promoting something undesirable, always used in combination
>
> *warmonger, sleazemonger*

When used by someone who isn't a Perl programmer themselves, is "Perl Monger" derogatory?

Comment: PHP-monger would be offensive.

Comment: I'm surprised that the two most common instances of words that include the *-monger* combining form that you are familiar with are *whoremonger* and *warmonger* (though there has admittedly been a glut of warmongers of late). Wiktionary's first definition, "A dealer in a specific commodity, normally used in combination", gives as examples *costermonger, fishmonger, ironmonger*. Other common *-monger* words are *fearmonger, rumourmonger, scandalmonger* and *cheesemonger*.

Comment: @ErikKowal I'm not sure what you're implying, but I most likely heard whoremonger from the Bible.

Comment: @ErikKowal -- note that no one actually says *costermonger* or *ironmonger*.  I bet most people don't even know what a *coster* is (hint: it's an apple).  They do say *fearmonger* and *rumormonger*, exactly because of the negative implications.  Even *fishmonger*, in the rare occasions it is used nowadays, is used in some joke or another.

Comment: @Malvolio - Maybe there are no ironmongers or fishmongers wherever it is you live, but they still exist elsewhere – for instance, there are still plenty of both to be found in Britain, where they are also referred to by those terms. But Britain's  costermongers (which I never claimed were still around) are indeed extinct; their barrows have been replaced by market stalls and lorries/trucks.

Comment: @ErikKowal -- there are certainly fishmongers where I live (SF), but _nobody calls them that_.  Maybe it's a US/UK thing?

Comment: @Malvolio - Out of curiosity, what *do* you call such a seller in SF? The only one I know of in the KS town I live in simply calls itself a 'fish company', which is very bland and generic-sounding.

Comment: @ErikKowal -- the institution is a "seafood market".  An individual who sells fish would be... a "fish guy", I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's meant in a *jocular*, rather than derogatory, fashion, rather like when they refer to themselves as "code-monkeys".

Comment: As a former programmer myself, I would like to second @Mal's opinion.

Answer (score 3):

As a Perlmonger myself, I don't find it derogatory, but would rather take it as a joking reference implying that I am attempting to promote ("sell") Perl, perhaps more than I should, in the eyes of the speaker.  Note that its mere usage implies the speaker does not much care for Perl as a language.  Those of us who code in Perl would probably call ourselves "Perl jockeys" if we wanted to be positive about ourselves, which we rarely do.  After all, we code in Perl!

I think "Perlmonger" implies a somewhat colorful, even slightly cartoonish, indication of the undesirability of Perl in the eyes of the speaker, but I don't infer any judgment being passed on the monger themselves, merely on the language (or the desirability of evangelizing it). I don't think it would be taken as any more offensive than calling a person a "LAMP stacker", a group a "Microsoft Shop", or other terms of that ilk, intended to indicate that the language/environment in question is inexplicably popular and is not the favored medium of the speaker.

Note that, of course, context is everything. It's certainly possible to use the term in the middle of a screed against a particular set of programmers, in which case Perlmonger is likely one of the least-objectionable epithets that would be hurled at them, but it could still be interpreted as derogatory in such a context, as would "Microsoft Shop", etc.